# Is the projection $\pi:R^3 \to R^2$ given by $ \pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$ on a regular suface continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry, projection

$\pi:R^3 \to R^2$ given by $ \pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$

In the textbook, *do Carmo-Differential geometry of curves & surfaces*, page 66, the proof of proposition 4, it says that the projection $\pi$ restricted on a neighborhood is continuous.

I think that the projection defined by $\pi$ is continuous on $R^3$, and I wonder if condition in the proposition 4: **$S$ is a regular surface** is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction of a continuous map to *any* topological subspace whatsoever is always continuous. The hypotheses are used for the rest of the argument — in particular, to apply the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so to apply the inverse function theorem the $S$ must be regular surface?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much and I get it now!

Comment: By the way, I wonder if the definition of continuous map refers to continuous in $R^3$? Because I consulted my teacher and he told me that the domain of $\pi$ must inherit the toplogy of $R^3$. And it means that the surface $S$ must be regular surface. So I am a a little bit confused that  which explanation is true.